# Blender 2.79 How to remove these black lines in Cycles Render?

Tags: rendering

Those black lines appear on each edge that's have separated two faces.
Is there a way to get rid of them?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I can't tell for sure by looking at the image, but it looks like the geometry is manifold (some edges belong to more than 2 faces). This can cause shading issues (and other issues). Try to always make the geometry non-manifold.

Comment: Yes you're right some edges belong to more than 2 faces. 
I see... so that's bad.
Thank you.